# How to avoid long for-loops for creating multiple arrays (javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I´m stuck with a problem... given an input number I´m trying to output a string of length 4. The string has to be divided into 2 parameter sections "On"/"Off".

For example:

-If the input number is 16, then the string should get combined as follows:

- "On" section = "On" * Math.floor(16/5) = 3 --> "On On On".
- "Off" section should be: length-On-section = 4-3 = 1 --> "Off".
- Hence the string should look like "On On On Off".

I´m currently trying to narrow my solution to a nicer approach than using a for loop. I have to repeat this process various times in my function to create strings following the same approach but in various lengths and "On"/"Off" section ratios. but I´m not sure how to set it up properly..

this is one example:

---

```
function hoursTop(hour) {
var lights = [], on = Math.floor(hour/5), off = 4 - topLightsOn;

for(var i=1; i<=on; i++){
lights.push('On');
}
for(var j=1; j<=Off; j++){
lights.push('Off');
}
return lights.join("");
}
```

This produces way too much code overall.. Thanks for helping me out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [String#repeat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat) to create the strings, then concat them, and trim the extra spaces:

```js
function hoursTop(hour) {
  var on = Math.floor(hour/5), off = 4 - on;
  
  return 'on '.repeat(on) + 'off '.repeat(off).trim();
}

console.log(hoursTop(16));
```

Or you can use [Array#fill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) to create the array, then concat them, and join the array to a string:

```js
function hoursTop(hour) {
  var on = Math.floor(hour/5), off = 4 - on;
  
  return Array(on).fill('on').concat(Array(off).fill('off')).join(' ');
}

console.log(hoursTop(16));
```